# Block a resource for only one user in laravel PHP AJAX and redirect the other to a readonly form

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5, dom-events, laravel-middleware

I create an application with laravel 5.5. I use so PHP AJAX and MySQL.

I have a problem. An user connect with his account on the application and when he will click on an element (for example a contact card), I want to redirect this user on a form in readonly because another user is in current card. This another user see the form to edit the card.

In fact, I want to block a resource for only one user in edit. The other users will be in readonly (redirect to another route)

Is it possible to use a middleware? Use the cookies? Or launch an Ajax route when the user close his browser or tab page?

Help me....

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please, provide code you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add new nullable field to the database on your resource to keep current user id that responsible for the edit. Then add a middlware which will check if this field is null then free to edit, if not be readonly.

for example you have a products table:

id  title    group_id editor_id

---

1   bicycle  1        5

2   car      3        null

Resource id 1 only be editable by user id 5.

Resource id 2 is editable any user who start editing.

and then after the user exit or any other behavior you like, try to make it null again to be editable by others.

middlware code:

```
// find the resource
$resource = Resource::find($request->resource_id);

// current user is last user. so no need to check.
if($resource->editor_id == auth()->user()->id) return $next($request);

// check if 10 minutes passed from last edit by another user.
if(Carbon::now()->diffInMinutes(Carbon::parse($resource->updated_at)) >= 10) {
    // replace current user id with last one.
    $resource->editor_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $resource->save();
} else {
    return response('You dont have permission to edit.');
}
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks you for your response. I think do it to edit or readonly route but I don't know how to reinitialize the field at ''null'' when the user close his browser. Maybe with option on laravel cookie 'expire on close '' ? What do you think about ?

Comment: Your welcome. You can replace user_id instead of making null. Only try to replace new  user_id on new user request to edit with considering this condition that N hours passed from last update (`now - updated_at > N hour`).

Comment: 1/ Good idea, so I create a variable to limit usage of a resource, (for example 10min) and with your condition from last update, I set at "null" the field. Good job :).

But I'm a newbie on laravel, have you an example for the middleware condition ? Else it does not matter ;). Thanks you so much again :).

2/ And do you have already run a command or a script when the user change of url ? Example : I click on my current card, and when I want to change, a popup open the message "Bye bye :)".

Comment: for your second question You can find what you need in this [link](https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Capture-Browser-Or-Tab-Close-Event-Jquery-Javascript)

Comment: Wah wah wah ! Thanks you :). I work it this week on this middleware and more tests ! Thanks you again, I have a good solution with your example !!

Comment: Good luck. If it was useful, please mark it as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use both the approach;

1. **Handle it through Laravel Middleware on server side** - You would need to create a middleware that should check on resource call. You would also need to maintain the update flag against resource for a particular session request so that it shouldn’t be available to others.
2. **Client Side check on availability of the resource** - Once a resource is dispatched by other user current user who is seeing the resource as **Ready Only** , can work on it with the latest data on the form.

Moreover, you can manage the queue of requests to handle such priority so that if multiple users are viewing the resource they should be able to get as per their precedence depending on the priority set bu you.

Comment: Thanks you for your response, have you already do this with the second method?

Comment: Yeah, you can discuss it further with me.